# Can a webserver use a cloud storage like Drive, Dropbox, etc. to access web files?

Tags: webserver, cloud

Currently I have a website that stores many song lyrics (each song as a file), and when the user selects one from a list, the site displays the contents of the song file.

I want to be able to change the song folder very easily, which is possible if they are stored in a cloud service like Dropbox or Google Drive. Is it possible for my website to access the files from Dropbox (or similar), instead of deploying the folder to the server each time I update the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for my website to access the files from Dropbox (or similar)..?

Yes, you can definitely do this.

In high level terms you can either:

- have your back end, i.e. the web server, query the dropbox or equivalent and then return the results to the front end, i.e. the browser and any Javascript client you have running in the client
- have your browser based client access the dropbox or equivalent directly

In either case you will use whatever API the dropbox etc provides - most will be RESTful or at least HTTP based. For example the Dropbox api is here:

- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs

Comment: I looked a little at the dropbox api, and it seems more like accessing the *user's* dropbox, needing their login etc. My question was more directed towards the site having its own account from which it pulls files (and reads the files, instead of presenting them directly to the user). Is that possible?

Comment: Yes - your server can be a 'user' for example and securely retrieve files. Look at the '/files (GET)' method in the API.